# How to setup a recursive lapply for specific values ex.w[i] == n[i]?

Tags: r, recursion, lapply

**Background**

I'm developing a function that takes in a value for `w` between 1 and 3 and returns `n` values from one of 3 distributions.
The problem I am having is when `n` or `w` are not of length 1. So I've added 2 parameters `nIsList` and `wIsList` to create the functionality I want. The way I want this to work is as follows:

**(*Works as needed*)**

`If nIsList ex( c(1,2,3) )` return a list equivalent to running consume(w,1), consume(w,2), consume(w,3)

**(*Works as needed*)**

`If wIsList ex( c(1,2,3) )` return a list equivalent to running consume(1,n), consume(2,n), consume(3,n)

**(*Doesn't work as needed*)**

`If nIsList ex(1,2,3) and wIsList ex(1,2,3)` 
return a list equivalent to running consume(1,1), consume(2,2), consume(3,3). Instead, I get a list equivalent to running [consume(1,1), consume(1,2), consume(1,3)], [consume(2,1), consume(2,2), consume(2,3)], [consume(3,1),consume(3,2), consume(3,3)]

I understand why I am getting the results I am getting. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the result I want. (As explained above)

**Question**

I want the function to provide a list for each element in w and n that is consume(w[i], n[i]) when wIsList & nIsList are True. Is there a way to do that using lapply?

**The code:**

```
library("triangle")
consume <- function(w, n=1, nIsList=F, wIsList=F){
  if(!nIsList & !wIsList){  
    if(w==1){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.3,0.8))
    }else if(w==2){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.7,1))
    }else if(w==3){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.9,2,1.3))
    }
  }
  else if(nIsList & !wIsList){
    return(sapply(n, consume, w=w))
  }
  else if(nIsList & wIsList){
    return(lapply(n, consume, w=w, wIsList=T))
  }
  else if(!nIsList & wIsList){
    return(lapply(w, consume, n))
  }
}
```

Note: I am having trouble summarizing this question. If you have any suggestions for renaming it please let me know and I will do so.

Comment: have you taken a look at `mapply`? seems like that would do it

Comment: cool no problem, sorry that couldn't type out an answer was on my mobile :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JPC's comment, using `mapply` does the trick. The new code is as follows:

```
consume <- function(w, n=1){
  nIsList <- length(n) > 1 # Change based on JPC's second comment
  wIsList <- length(w) > 1 # Change based on JPC's second comment
  if(!nIsList & !wIsList){  
    if(w==1){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.3,0.8))
    }else if(w==2){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.7,1))
    }else if(w==3){
      return(rtriangle(n,0.9,2,1.3))
    }
  }
  else if(nIsList & !wIsList){
    return(sapply(n, consume, w=w))
  }
  else if(nIsList & wIsList){
    return(mapply(consume,w,n)) ## Updated portion
  }
  else if(!nIsList & wIsList){
    return(lapply(w, consume, n)) 
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, you could also count the length of `n` or `w` to figure out if they are a list (i.e. `lenght(w)>1`, so that you can avoidf having to pass along `isList` parameters.

Comment: I was debating doing that. Sometimes I want the function to use the length of the vector used instead of the actual attributes but I guess I should enter that as the parameter instead of having the function work this way. Will update it. Thanks!